# Arduino-ESP8266 project in CLion - how to compile project properly?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, clion, platformio

1. I had my project in Arduino which uses arduino-esp8266 library.
2. I entered the folder of my project and executed: `platformio init
   --ide clion --board esp07`.
3. Then I copied my project's source files into `src` folder.
4. I run CLion, imported the project and figured out that auto-completion and refactoring is not working.
5. I copied arduino-esp8266 library to `lib` folder in my project's main folder.
6. I changed my `CMakeListsPrivate.txt` to look like this:

`CMakeListsPrivate.txt`:

```
set(ENV{PATH} "C:\\Users\\Defozo\\.atom\\packages\\platformio-ide\\penv\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\Defozo\\.atom\\packages\\platformio-ide\\penv\\Scripts;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\bin;C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\Bpl;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\bin64;C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\Bpl\\Win64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Projects\\Bpl\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;D:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Users\\Defozo\\.dnx\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft DNX\\Dnvm\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CMake\\bin;D:\\Anaconda2;D:\\Anaconda2\\Scripts;D:\\Anaconda2\\Library\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Shared;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nordic Semiconductor\\nrf5x\\bin\\;D:\\comapre;D:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2009b\\runtime\\win64;D:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2009b\\bin;D:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\;D:\\Ruby22-x64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\;D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_74\\bin;D:\\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\\bin;C:\\Users\\Defozo\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\bin;D:\\Program Files\\Docker Toolbox;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\bin;C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\Bpl;D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\bin64;C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\Embarcadero\\Studio\\17.0\\Bpl\\Win64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Borland\\Delphi7\\Projects\\Bpl\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;D:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Users\\Defozo\\.dnx\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft DNX\\Dnvm\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CMake\\bin;D:\\Anaconda2;D:\\Anaconda2\\Scripts;D:\\Anaconda2\\Library\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Shared;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nordic Semiconductor\\nrf5x\\bin\\;D:\\comapre;D:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2009b\\runtime\\win64;D:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2009b\\bin;D:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\;D:\\Ruby22-x64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\;D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_74\\bin;D:\\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\\bin;C:\\Users\\Defozo\\AppData\\Local\\atom\\bin;D:\\Program Files\\Docker Toolbox")
set(PLATFORMIO_CMD "C:\\Users\\Defozo\\.atom\\packages\\platformio-ide\\penv\\Scripts\\platformio.exe")

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/Users/Defozo/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc.exe")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/Users/Defozo/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++.exe")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DISTRIBUTION "-fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -std=c++11 -Os -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -falign-functions=4 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DARDUINO=20300 -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DF_CPU=80000000L -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -DPLATFORMIO=30300 -DESP8266 -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_ESP07 -U__STRICT_ANSI__")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DISTRIBUTION "-std=gnu99 -Wpointer-arith -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -Wl,-EL -fno-inline-functions -nostdlib -Os -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -falign-functions=4 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DARDUINO=20300 -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DF_CPU=80000000L -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -DPLATFORMIO=30300 -DESP8266 -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_ESP07 -U__STRICT_ANSI__")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_definitions(-DARDUINO=20300)
add_definitions(-DLWIP_OPEN_SRC)
add_definitions(-DF_CPU=80000000L)
add_definitions(-D__ets__)
add_definitions(-DICACHE_FLASH)
add_definitions(-DPLATFORMIO=30300)
add_definitions(-DESP8266)
add_definitions(-DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266)
add_definitions(-DARDUINO_ESP8266_ESP07)

include_directories("D:/Arduino/2/laser_na_stacje_v2/src")

include_directories("$ENV{HOMEDRIVE}$ENV{HOMEPATH}/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/xtensa-lx106-elf/include")
include_directories("$ENV{HOMEDRIVE}$ENV{HOMEPATH}/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/include")
include_directories("$ENV{HOMEDRIVE}$ENV{HOMEPATH}/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/include-fixed")

file(GLOB_RECURSE Foo_SOURCES "D:/Arduino/2/laser_na_stacje_v2/lib/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE Foo_HEADERS "D:/Arduino/2/laser_na_stacje_v2/lib/*.h")

set (Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS "")
foreach (_headerFile ${Foo_HEADERS})
    get_filename_component(_dir ${_headerFile} PATH)
    list (APPEND Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS ${_dir})
endforeach()
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS)

include_directories(${Foo_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable (laser_na_stacje_v2-2 ${Foo_SOURCES})

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_LIST "D:/Arduino/2/laser_na_stacje_v2/src/*.*")
```

7. And I changed my `CMakeLists.txt` to this:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(laser_na_stacje_v2)

include(CMakeListsPrivate.txt)

add_custom_target(
    PLATFORMIO_BUILD ALL
    COMMAND ${PLATFORMIO_CMD} -f -c clion run
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    PLATFORMIO_UPLOAD ALL
    COMMAND ${PLATFORMIO_CMD} -f -c clion run --target upload
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    PLATFORMIO_CLEAN ALL
    COMMAND ${PLATFORMIO_CMD} -f -c clion run --target clean
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    PLATFORMIO_TEST ALL
    COMMAND ${PLATFORMIO_CMD} -f -c clion test
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    PLATFORMIO_PROGRAM ALL
    COMMAND ${PLATFORMIO_CMD} -f -c clion run --target program
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    PLATFORMIO_UPLOADFS ALL
    COMMAND ${PLATFORMIO_CMD} -f -c clion run --target uploadfs
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    PLATFORMIO_UPDATE_ALL ALL
    COMMAND ${PLATFORMIO_CMD} -f -c clion update
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_custom_target(
    PLATFORMIO_REBUILD_PROJECT_INDEX ALL
    COMMAND ${PLATFORMIO_CMD} -f -c clion init --ide clion
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/laser_na_stacje_v2.cpp)
```

8. After that operations the auto-completion and refactoring is working. However, I can't now compile my project.

When I choose `PLATFORMIO_BUILD` and click Run then I see:

```
"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\cmake-build-debug --target PLATFORMIO_BUILD -- -j 8
[05/17/17 12:08:54] Processing esp07 (platform: espressif8266, board: esp07, framework: arduino)

Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
Collected 31 compatible libraries
Looking for dependencies...
Library Dependency Graph
|-- <SPI> v1.0
|-- <Adafruit BMP280 Library> v1.0.1
|   |-- <Wire> v1.0
|   |-- <Adafruit Unified Sensor> v1.0.2
|   |-- <SPI> v1.0
|-- <Adafruit_BMP085>
|   |-- <Wire> v1.0
|-- <ESP8266httpUpdate> v1.1
|   |-- <ESP8266HTTPClient> v1.1
|   |   |-- <ESP8266WiFi> v1.0
|   |-- <ESP8266WiFi> v1.0
|-- <EEPROM> v1.0
|-- <DHT sensor library> v1.2.3
|-- <serialReadPMValue>
|-- <Json>
|-- <WifiManager> v0.10
|   |-- <DNSServer> v1.1.0
|   |   |-- <ESP8266WiFi> v1.0
|   |-- <ESP8266WebServer> v1.0
|   |   |-- <ESP8266WiFi> v1.0
|   |-- <ESP8266WiFi> v1.0
|-- <ESP8266WiFi> v1.0
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\src\laser_na_stacje_v2.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\SPI\SPI.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\Adafruit_BMP280_Library\Adafruit_BMP280.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\ArduinoJson\Internals\JsonParser.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\ArduinoJson\Internals\List.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\ArduinoJson\Internals\Prettyfier.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\ArduinoJson\Internals\StaticStringBuilder.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\ArduinoJson\JsonArray.o
Archiving .pioenvs\esp07\lib\libSPI.a
Archiving .pioenvs\esp07\lib\libAdafruit_BMP280_Library.a
Indexing .pioenvs\esp07\lib\libAdafruit_BMP280_Library.a
Indexing .pioenvs\esp07\lib\libSPI.a
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\ArduinoJson\JsonBuffer.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\ArduinoJson\JsonObject.o
Compiling .pioenvs\esp07\lib\ArduinoJson\JsonVariant.o
Archiving .pioenvs\esp07\lib\libArduinoJson.a
Indexing .pioenvs\esp07\lib\libArduinoJson.a
Linking .pioenvs\esp07\firmware.elf
Calculating size .pioenvs\esp07\firmware.elf
Building .pioenvs\esp07\firmware.bin
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename
379874    13232   31040  424146   678d2 .pioenvs\esp07\firmware.elf
 [SUCCESS] Took 4.73 seconds 
Built target PLATFORMIO_BUILD

"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\cmake-build-debug --target laser_na_stacje_v2 -- -j 8
Scanning dependencies of target laser_na_stacje_v2
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2.dir/src/laser_na_stacje_v2.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable laser_na_stacje_v2.exe
c:/users/defozo/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--out-implib'
c:/users/defozo/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld.exe: use the --help option for usage information
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'laser_na_stacje_v2.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [laser_na_stacje_v2.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:399: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:411: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [laser_na_stacje_v2] Error 2
Makefile:234: recipe for target 'laser_na_stacje_v2' failed
```

And if I choose `laser_na_stacje_v2-2` and click Run:

```
"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.1\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\cmake-build-debug --target laser_na_stacje_v2-2 -- -j 8
[  0%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/ArduinoString_Tests.cpp.obj
[  1%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Array_Tests.cpp.obj
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Basic_Tests.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_NoMemory_Tests.cpp.obj
[  3%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Object_Tests.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/GbathreeBug.cpp.obj
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/IntegrationTests.cpp.obj
[  5%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/Issue10.cpp.obj
D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\lib\ArduinoJson\test\DynamicJsonBuffer_Basic_Tests.cpp:7:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\lib\ArduinoJson\test\ArduinoString_Tests.cpp:7:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir\build.make:462: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Basic_Tests.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Basic_Tests.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\lib\ArduinoJson\test\DynamicJsonBuffer_Array_Tests.cpp:7:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir\build.make:412: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/ArduinoString_Tests.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/ArduinoString_Tests.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir\build.make:437: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Array_Tests.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Array_Tests.cpp.obj] Error 1
D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\lib\ArduinoJson\test\DynamicJsonBuffer_Object_Tests.cpp:7:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\lib\ArduinoJson\test\DynamicJsonBuffer_NoMemory_Tests.cpp:7:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir\build.make:512: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Object_Tests.cpp.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir\build.make:487: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_NoMemory_Tests.cpp.obj' failed
D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\lib\ArduinoJson\test\GbathreeBug.cpp:7:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_Object_Tests.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/DynamicJsonBuffer_NoMemory_Tests.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir\build.make:537: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/GbathreeBug.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/GbathreeBug.cpp.obj] Error 1
D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\lib\ArduinoJson\test\IntegrationTests.cpp:7:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir\build.make:562: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/IntegrationTests.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/IntegrationTests.cpp.obj] Error 1
D:\Arduino\2\laser_na_stacje_v2\lib\ArduinoJson\test\Issue10.cpp:7:25: fatal error: gtest/gtest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/Issue10.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir\build.make:587: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/lib/ArduinoJson/test/Issue10.cpp.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/laser_na_stacje_v2-2.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [laser_na_stacje_v2-2] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'laser_na_stacje_v2-2' failed
```

What should I do to have auto-completion, refactoring and compiling working?

Answer (score 1):

1. create your project folder, `$ mkdir ~/pio/test`
2. then run `$ platformio init --ide clion --board nodemcuv2`
3. then download sources for esp8266
   `$ curl -o ~/pio/test/src/main.cpp https://raw.githubusercontent.com/platformio/platformio-examples/develop/espressif/esp8266-arduino-ota/src/main.cpp

   $ curl -o ~/pio/test/lib/ArduinoOTA/ArduinoOTA.cpp https://raw.githubusercontent.com/platformio/platformio-examples/develop/espressif/esp8266-arduino-ota/lib/ArduinoOTA/ArduinoOTA.cpp

   $ curl -o ~/pio/test/lib/ArduinoOTA/ArduinoOTA.h https://raw.githubusercontent.com/platformio/platformio-examples/develop/espressif/esp8266-arduino-ota/lib/ArduinoOTA/ArduinoOTA.h`
4. then repeat `$ platformio init --ide clion --board nodemcuv2`
5. Open Clion. Import this project via Menu: File > Import Project and specify root directory where is located Project Configuration File platformio.ini
6. Build project (DO NOT RUN): Menu: Run > Build

Useful links:
`http://tiestvangool.ghost.io/2017/01/12/ota-platformio-and-esp8266/`
`http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/ide/clion.html`

And use this button [for build project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEIrE.png)

Comment: When importing the project, should the `CMakeLIsts.txt` file be overwritten?